# Is password --encrypted and password --md5 the same for the GRUB config file?

Tags: linux, configuration, password, grub

In my 2 Linux servers I have the below entries in `/etc/grub.conf`.

Server 1 :

```
  password --encrypted $1$something$somevalue.
```

Server 2:

```
  password --md5 $1$something$somevalue.
```

My question is are they the same ? Is there any difference between the usage of `--encrypted` and `--md5`?

Comment: Are you using `grub-crypt` ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check if I am using `grub-crypt` ? I am new to this . I could see in my system `grub-crypt` is available . But I am not sure if it is used for GRUB .

Comment: `grub-crypt` is used to generate a passwd for grub1 there is a tuto [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/grub-password-command) and `grub2-mkpasswd-pbkdf2` for grub2 [tuto](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/01/06/how-to-password-protect-grub-entries/)

Comment: I am using  0.97. So it should be grub1 right